# Adding Animations in sencha modern apps

Tags: javascript, animation, extjs, responsive-design

We have been using sencha modern 6.5 for developing our mobile app. We are at the point of adding animations to our app's different components and actions. We have tried using sencha's animations but they fall short of our expectations. An [example](https://uxplanet.org/animated-transitions-in-mobile-apps-412b8e8478e7) of what we would like to implement in our app.
        Do you have any recommendations for any mobile js frameworks or design tools? How well do tools like google web designer or adobe edge animate integrate with sencha? I have tried using greensock but sometimes it comes into conflict with sencha's default animations(e.g.cardswitch)..

Comment: Hi I am new to stackoverflow.com!! Can someone pls explain why my question is downvoted?? Is something wrong with my question?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why your question is so downvoted, but maybe it's because you don't use a line break between your sentences.

This can break reading..

Also you don't give details like you'r ExtJS version.

Have you tried to use this : https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.2/modern/Ext.Anim.html ?